# How do I fix my Python function so that it returns with input prompts?

Tags: python, function

I have a menu function and choice function that both worked. There are 3 menu choices. 1 and 3 worked properly at one point. 2 never has. I don't know what I did to mess it up, but when I run the module to test through IDLE, it doesn't ever work past the first prompting to enter my menu choice number. It should complete an if statement, then restart.

I don't know what else to try. I wish I knew what I changed to mess it up.

```
tribbles = 1
modulus = 2
closer= 3

def menu():
    print('    -MENU-')
    print('1: Tribbles Exchange')
    print('2: Odd or Even?')
    print("3: I'm not in the mood...")

menu()
def choice():
    choice = int(input('\n Enter the number of your menu choice: ')


if choice == tribbles:
    bars = int(input('\n How many bars of gold-pressed latinum do you have? '))
    print('\n You can buy ',bars * 5000 / 1000,' Tribbles.')
    menu()
    choice()
elif choice == modulus:
    num = int(input('\n Enter any number:'))
    o_e = num % 2
    if num == 0:
        print(num,' is an even number')
    elif num == 1:
        print(num,' is an odd number')
    menu()
    choice()
elif choice == closer:
    print('\n Thanks for playing!')
    exit()
else:
    print('Invalid entry. Please try again...')
    menu()
    choice()
print(' ')
choice = int(input('\n Enter the number of your menu choice: '))
```

I expect it to return with the string plus all formula results, then asking again, unless option 3 was selected and exit() is performed. However it returns with "Enter the number of your menu choice: " after the first input, then it returns blank after choosing any other choice on the second prompt.f

Answer (score 1):

Before you check the value of `choice`, the variable `choice` is not declared. You have to catch your input before the line: `if choice == tribbles:`. Your are only defining a function which even don't return the value of your choice or set a global variable.

Try this:

```
def menu():
    print('    -MENU-')
    print('1: Tribbles Exchange')
    print('2: Odd or Even?')
    print("3: I'm not in the mood...")

menu()
choice = int(input('\n Enter the number of your menu choice: '))

if choice == tribbles:
...
```

Comment: For some reason, it gives an error when running: "Invalid syntax." and it points to the ":" after 'if choice == tribbles'

Comment: a bracket was missing after the input()... I edit the post

Answer (score 1):

First things first!

It's good practice to define all functions at the top of the file, and call those functions at the bottom! Second your indenting is incorrect, i'm going to assume that happened after you pasted it here. Finally, you never actually call the function `choice()` you instead overwrite it with the result of a prompt.

Below i'm going to correct these issues.

```
tribbles = 1
modulus = 2
closer= 3

def menu():
    print('    -MENU-')
    print('1: Tribbles Exchange')
    print('2: Odd or Even?')
    print("3: I'm not in the mood...")
    choice() #added call to choice here because you always call choice after menu

def choice():
    my_choice = int(raw_input('\nEnter the number of your menu choice: ')) #you were missing a ) here! and you were overwriting the function choice again
    #changed choice var to my_choice everywhere

    if my_choice == tribbles:
        bars = int(raw_input('\nHow many bars of gold-pressed latinum do you have? '))
        print('\n You can buy ',bars * 5000 / 1000,' Tribbles.')
        menu()
    elif my_choice == modulus:
        num = int(raw_input('\n Enter any number:'))
        o_e = num % 2
        if num == 0:
            print(num,' is an even number')
        elif num == 1:
            print(num,' is an odd number')
        menu()
    elif choice == closer:
        print('\n Thanks for playing!')
        exit()
    else:
        print('Invalid entry. Please try again...')
        menu()
    print(' ')


if __name__ == "__main__": #standard way to begin. This makes sure this is being called from this file and not when being imported. And it looks pretty!
    menu()
```

Comment: Thank you to the answerers. I ended up sacrificing the looping back to allow for more choices. TheLazyScripter's solution allowed it, but I was overwhelmed. If you can't tell, I am brand new to programming. I'm in a fundamentals of programming logic class right now.